# How to make Windows Application available on the web?

Tags: c#

This might be a silly question..

I created a windows application in C# that works from my computer where SQL server database is residing. In this windows application all i do is fire two events and it give a bit output.

Can i create a simple webpage with two buttons and a text box and allow users on the web start my windows application residing on my desktop and see the result?

Is it possible to invoke a windows application using webserver? This could be absurd as this would be a security issue..but any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If your app is written in C# could you create a ASP.NET webapp reusing the code, without having to start the windows app?

Comment: You may have to start thinking in terms of clients and servers.

Comment: Webservice would be right thing

Comment: No, you can't make Windows applications available on the web. You need to create a web application. The names weren't chosen randomly, they actually do mean something.

Comment: You probably should be looking at using something like WCF to control the communication to a common service - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really re-architect this with appropriate infrastructure.

One option would be your existing client, with a ClickOnce wrapper, and switching the data-access to use a web-service that you expose (with appropriate security etc) via a web server. However, this limits you to windows clients - as would xbap or WPF (plus xbap/WPF is a UI rewrite).

Silverlight has a little more flexibility but is a complete UI rewrite.

Personally, I think your best option is to bite the bullet and re-engineer it as a web-based application; html, jQuery, etc - and MVC or WebForms, etc (since you're familiar with .NET).

Comment: I think i have a workaround, i can use twitter for this purpose. people who ever want to run my application residing on my desktop will tweet me say...runapp...my application will be here busy wait on twitter messages and when ever it gets a new tweet saying runapp it will run and post the latest result to twitter. whats your opinion?

Comment: @Krishna depends on the data, of course... it'll probably work, but.... well, up to you ;p

Answer (score 0):

You're using WinForms (standard Windows app), you'd like to use WebForms for a Web application. A Web application sends HTML so you're not likely to use directly what you did, or as Twelve47 says you'll have to use ASP.NET and deploy your app on a IIS server.

The easiest might be (if the users are part of your local network) to share a dedicated folder on your disk with sufficient rights for external people to be able to use your app.