# How to run a windows application as a web application

Tags: c#

I did a windows application project with C#. Now, I wanna to run it as web application.(I mean, i want to install the application on server and the user from other places can connect to the server with a web link and test it).Since all the user do not have the visua studio software, I forced to do that. May you help me to figure this problem out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say a windows application project do you mean a Winforms app? I suspect you'll need to build a different type of project - look at MVC or WebForms (asp.net) applications

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728751/how-to-make-windows-application-available-on-the-web?rq=1

Comment: Hi couple of clarifications, is your requirement that it be hosted on a web server OR that other users can run your app on their computers? You mention "Since all the user do not have the visua studio software" but people do not need visual studio on their computers. They would (as you'd expect) need the .NET runtime though.

Comment: I mean, this application must stand alone. I wrote this application for an organization and know they want to test it by themselves and then it must not need any special thing to run.Any idea @jdphenix?

Comment: @user3371238 why can't you just deploy a compiled, beta version of your app for them to play with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer: you can't run a Windows application directly in a web environment**. And really there is NO WAY you should want that, either.

If you need remote access to the computer running the instance of your application, that can be done with the right software. I can think of [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com), [Radmin](http://www.radmin.com/) and Remote Desktop on top of my head.

If support for multiple concurrent users is required then you have two obvious choices:

1. Deploy your application on every clients, or
2. Make a Web application.

Now for option 1, there are different ways to do that. Depending of the complexity of your app you may require a Windows Installer setup package. For this there is multiple tools on the net. My personal favorite is [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/). Free, powerful and easy once you get the hang of it. Most installers will also ensure that requirements for the app to run are met, and install the missing components if necessary.

If all you have is a simple EXE file then you could be tempted to just package (ZIP) it and share it any way you want, but be warned: if the correct .NET Framework isn't installed on the client machine, it won't work. IMHO given the tools at your disposition to ensure a proper installation experience for the end user, you have no reason to do that. You can, however, consider using ClickOnce for this scenario.

If that doesn't help you, then please add more details on what your requirements are, maybe you'll get better advice.

PS: About "not every users having the Visual Studio software"... having VS installed should never, EVER be a requirement for the regular user.

Comment: The application has done by Windows Form Application. I have to change it to web application that every one can access that and run it or change it to stand alone application that need anything to run (no need to Visual Studio) and I give to the customer the "EXE" file and they run it their own machine @Crono

Comment: You can't just magically convert an actual Winform application into a Web one. If deployment of your Winform app is what you need then just do that. If *that's* what you need help for, you are not asking the right question.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Crono . I think  "If all you have is a simple EXE file then you could be tempted to just package (ZIP) it and share it any way you want, but be warned: if the correct .NET Framework isn't installed on the client machine, it won't work. IMHO given the tools at your disposition to ensure a proper installation experience for the end user, you have no reason to do that" is a good idea. How I must find that which  .NET Framework is suitable? how to check it? Is it free?

Comment: .NET Framework is free. The suitable version would be of course the one you are building your app with.

Comment: Check for ClickOnce Deployment, it might give you what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).ASPX

Comment: *If support for multiple concurrent users is required then you will be left with no other choice than

Deploy your application on every clients, or
Make a Web application.* This actually isn't true. You can use application virtualizing software like [Citrix XenApp](http://www.citrix.com/products/xenapp/overview.html) It's expensive but it's commonly used in large organizations

Comment: There, I changed "no other choice" to "two obvious choices". ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You can have people be able to Remote Desktop to the server and then run the application. If you wanted it to be accessible via URL, you have to build a webpage.

Comment: The application has done by Windows Form Application. I have to change it to web application that every one can access that and run it or change it to stand alone application that need anything to run (no need to Visual Studio) and I give to the customer the "EXE" file and they run it their own machine @bobek

Comment: After you build your app, you can .zip and send them the "bin" folder from your application root folder. It will have the "exe" file that needs to be run.

Comment: By doing this, it does not need any special software like (Visual studio) to run?

Comment: No. But they might need to have .NET framework matching your build framework. Luckily .NET framework is a common thing to have on Windows machine so you might be in luck. Test it and see how it works.

Comment: I would advise against deploying a Winform app in such a simplistic way... no good reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just run a Windows application as a Web Application. You need to re-write it as a web application. The users do not need Visual Studio to run your application as you have mentioned in your question. If you give some details of what your application does then maybe you will get some better help.

Comment: ,The application has done by Windows Form Application. I have to change it to web application that every one can access that and run it or change it to stand alone application that need anything to run (no need to Visual Studio) and I give to the customer the "EXE" file and they run it their own machine, @LeeWillis

Comment: You can just compile your Windows Forms application and give it to them to run. Depending what version of the framework you have used and what they have installed that might be enough. You can try [http://smallestdotnet.com/] on their machines to see which version of the framework they have available. Which version of the framework have you used?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote your application using WPF it is possible to deploy it as an XBAP.
There are restrictions associated with deploying an application this way.

The minimum you would need to do is create a Web Application to host said XBAP.

Comment: The application has done by Windows Form Application. I have to change it to web application that every one can access that and run it or change it to stand alone application that need anything to run (no need to Visual Studio) and I give to the customer the "EXE" file and they run it their own machine @ywm

Comment: @user3371238 How about deploying the application with Click Once? May be worth updating your question with this information and relevant tags.